# How to force Browsers to get Data sequentially

Tags: html, http, tcp, embedded

Since I work with an embedded system my resources are limited. I implemented a minimal Webserver that will transfer simple html files from a SD-Card just fine. If the HTML includes graphics current Browsers try to get these images with multiple connections in parallel.
Having a max of 2 open files at a time i want to force the browsers to ideally have just one open connection and get the data one after another.

I tried the retry-after http header option in combination with response codes 503  (Service Unavailable) and 429 (Too Many Requests), but the Browsers don't care.

Closing the additional connections will result in no pictures displayed at all ( -> instant retry and fail )

Keeping the additional Connections open and sending the files one after another is an option, but i would need to manage alot of possible connections, wasting alot of ram.

Is there any other way of forcing the browser to work sequentially?

Comment: How much control do you have over the HTML? If you're generating it, you could use inline images instead of external ones.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something obvious, there is no way for HTTP servers to affect browsers' connection management. 
I'd consider an application layer solution where you track outstanding requests and do not open more than one file per IP (i.e. allow browsers to open connections, but do not go into file fetching until the other outstanding request has completed).

Comment: This is the solution i use right now. But the amount of ram for buffers is fixed, so every "unused" possible connection is a huge waste of ram - and I am running out of ram.

Comment: @V.G.: Then maybe your problem is elsewhere, like you need to find a way to memorize what you need to serve less verbosely. Try to find the minimal amount of data essential in those request to eventually construct a response to them (like address, file they request memorized for example by some ID). This should be possible if the micro is capable enough to run a web-server along with interfacing an SD card.

Comment: You can also slow down your accept calls - i.e. run accept() / send SYN/ACK after a certain delay.

Comment: The problem isn't the size of the incoming request but the static memory reserved for every possible connection - no matter if it will be used or not. I am using LWIP TCP/IP stack by the way. 

Closing additional connections will result in instant retries -> graphics will not be served. 

Limiting connections to one and ignoring additional Syn-Packets results in retransmissions and correct serving of the data. But the retransmission timeout is set to some seconds and increasing with every retry ( at least in Win7). So a page with lets say 5 very small images takes about 30 seconds to serve.

Comment: Thanks @V.G. , your problem is clear. Maybe the only other option I can think of is using SPDY or HTTP/2.0 which multiplex requests over a single connection. However, I'm not sure if your HTTP server includes support for this.